# Playing sound issue iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, audio, playing

What's wrong with this code?  I've used it before but now I'm getting these warnings...

warning: passing argument 2 of 'AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID' from incompatible pointer type

warning: passing argument 1 of 'AudioServicesPlaySystemSound' makes integer from pointer without a cast

```
-(void)playfireSound{

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fireSound" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef) url, &fireSound);   
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(fireSound);
}
```

Comment: Maybe show the declaration of fireSound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration of your fireSound variable is probably incorrect for use with this API.  Maybe you declared it as an object of some sort, instead of as an SystemSoundID, which is of type int.